# Why does a binary serialization of a float use 55 bytes?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a task to take millions of floats and store them in the database in batches of 5,000, as binary.  This is forcing me to learn interesting things about serialization performance.

One of the things that surprises me is the size of the serialized data, which is a factor of ten above what I expected.  This test shows me that a four-byte float is serialized to 55 bytes and an eight-byte double to 59 bytes.

What is happening here?  I expected it to simply split the float value into its four bytes.  What are the other 51 bytes?

```
private void SerializeFloat()
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    IFormatter iFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(10000000))
    {
        memoryStream.Capacity = 0;
        iFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, (Single)rnd.NextDouble());
        iFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, rnd.NextDouble());
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `BinaryFormatter` generates a ton of cruft.

Comment: Your example isn't realistic.  There is of course metadata for each individual item serialized.  It would be more realistic to measure serialization of a large array of double, or `List<double>`.

Comment: Have you tried storing the floats as 5000-element _arrays_ rather than 5000 individual elements? I imagine the overhead for a 5000 element array is not much bigger than the header for a single float, and it would be amortized over the 5000 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binary serialization is *type safe*.  It makes sure that when you *deserialize* the data, you'll get the exact same object back.

To make that work, BinaryFormatter adds additional data about the types of the objects that you serialize.  You are seeing that extra overhead.  You can see it by serializing to a FileStream and looking at the generated file with a hex viewer.  You'll see strings back, like "System.Single", the type name, and "m_value", the name of the field where the value is stored.  A good way to cut down on the overhead is to, say, serialize an array instead.

BinaryWriter is the exact opposite, very compact but not type-safe.  Plenty of alternatives are available in between.

Answer (score 5):

Serialization is more than simply blitting bits and bytes to a stream. Serialization is structured output. This structure accounts for your actual differences. The Framework encodes additional information which lets it know the type and number of objects in the serialized data, among many other possibilities. It is an implementation detail best left alone.

If you need unstructured output, [you could use `BinaryWriter` instead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Because it is maybe of interest for someone I decided to do this post about **What does the binary format of serialized .NET objects look like and how can we interpret it correctly?**

I have based all my research on the [.NET Remoting: Binary Format Data Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc236844.aspx) specification.

**Example class:**

To have a working example, I have created a simple class called `A` which contains 2 properties, one string and one integer value, they are called `SomeString` and `SomeValue`.

Class `A` looks like this:

```
[Serializable()]
public class A
{
    public string SomeString
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int SomeValue
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

For the serialization I used the `BinaryFormatter` of course:

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("test.txt");
bf.Serialize(sw.BaseStream, new A() { SomeString = "abc", SomeValue = 123 });
sw.Close();
```

As can be seen, I passed a new instance of class `A` containing `abc` and `123` as values.

**Example result data:**

If we look at the serialized result in an hex editor, we get something like this:

[image: Example result data]

**Let us interpret the example result data:**

According to the above mentioned specification (here is the direct link to the PDF: [[MS-NRBF].pdf](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/5/E/95EF66AF-9026-4BB0-A41D-A4F81802D92C/%5BMS-NRBF%5D.pdf)) every record within the stream is identified by the `RecordTypeEnumeration`. Section `2.1.2.1 RecordTypeNumeration` states:

> This enumeration identifies the type of the record. Each record (except for MemberPrimitiveUnTyped) starts with a record type enumeration. The size of the enumeration is one BYTE.

**SerializationHeaderRecord:**

So if we look back at the data we got, we can start interpreting the first byte:

[image: SerializationHeaderRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration]

As stated in `2.1.2.1 RecordTypeEnumeration` a value of `0` identifies the `SerializationHeaderRecord` which is specified in `2.6.1 SerializationHeaderRecord`:

> The SerializationHeaderRecord record MUST be the first record in a binary serialization. This record has the major and minor version of the format and the IDs of the top object and the headers.

It consists of:

- RecordTypeEnum (1 byte)
- RootId (4 bytes)
- HeaderId (4 bytes)
- MajorVersion (4 bytes)
- MinorVersion (4 bytes)

With that knowledge we can interpret the record containing 17 bytes:

[image: SerializationHeaderRecord_Complete]

`00` represents the `RecordTypeEnumeration` which is `SerializationHeaderRecord` in our case.

`01 00 00 00` represents the `RootId`

> If neither the BinaryMethodCall nor BinaryMethodReturn record is present in the serialization stream, the value of this field MUST contain the ObjectId of a Class, Array, or BinaryObjectString record contained in the serialization stream.

So in our case this should be the `ObjectId` with the value `1` (because the data is serialized using little-endian) which we will hopefully see again ;-)

`FF FF FF FF` represents the `HeaderId`

`01 00 00 00` represents the `MajorVersion`

`00 00 00 00` represents the `MinorVersion`

**BinaryLibrary:**

As specified, each record must begin with the `RecordTypeEnumeration`. As the last record is complete, we must assume that a new one begins.

Let us interpret the next byte:

[image: BinaryLibraryRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration]

As we can see, in our example the `SerializationHeaderRecord` it is followed by the `BinaryLibrary` record:

> The BinaryLibrary record associates an INT32 ID (as specified in [MS-DTYP] section 2.2.22) with a Library name. This allows other records to reference the Library name by using the ID. This approach reduces the wire size when there are multiple records that reference the same Library name.

It consists of:

- RecordTypeEnum (1 byte)
- LibraryId (4 bytes)
- LibraryName (variable number of bytes (which is a `LengthPrefixedString`))

As stated in `2.1.1.6 LengthPrefixedString`...

> The LengthPrefixedString represents a string value. The string is prefixed by the length of the UTF-8 encoded string in bytes. The length is encoded in a variable-length field with a minimum of 1 byte and a maximum of 5 bytes. To minimize the wire size, length is encoded as a variable-length field.

In our simple example the length is always encoded using `1 byte`. With that knowledge we can continue the interpretation of the bytes in the stream:

[image: BinaryLibraryRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration_LibraryId]

`0C` represents the `RecordTypeEnumeration` which identifies the `BinaryLibrary` record.

`02 00 00 00` represents the `LibraryId` which is `2` in our case.

Now the `LengthPrefixedString` follows:

[image: BinaryLibraryRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration_LibraryId_LibraryName]

`42` represents the length information of the `LengthPrefixedString` which contains the `LibraryName`.

In our case the length information of `42` (decimal 66) tell's us, that we need to read the next 66 bytes and interpret them as the `LibraryName`.

As already stated, the string is `UTF-8` encoded, so the result of the bytes above would be something like: `_WorkSpace_, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`

**ClassWithMembersAndTypes:**

Again, the record is complete so we interpret the `RecordTypeEnumeration` of the next one:

[image: ClassWithMembersAndTypesRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration]

`05` identifies a `ClassWithMembersAndTypes` record. Section `2.3.2.1 ClassWithMembersAndTypes` states:

> The ClassWithMembersAndTypes record is the most verbose of the Class records. It contains metadata about Members, including the names and Remoting Types of the Members. It also contains a Library ID that references the Library Name of the Class.

It consists of:

- RecordTypeEnum (1 byte)
- ClassInfo (variable number of bytes)
- MemberTypeInfo (variable number of bytes)
- LibraryId (4 bytes)

**ClassInfo:**

As stated in `2.3.1.1 ClassInfo` the record consists of:

- ObjectId (4 bytes)
- Name (variable number of bytes (which is again a `LengthPrefixedString`))
- MemberCount(4 bytes)
- MemberNames (which is a sequence of `LengthPrefixedString`'s where the number of items MUST be equal to the value specified in the `MemberCount` field.)

Back to the raw data, step by step:

[image: ClassWithMembersAndTypesRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration_ClassInfo_ObjectId]

`01 00 00 00` represents the `ObjectId`. We've already seen this one, it was specified as the `RootId` in the `SerializationHeaderRecord`.

[image: ClassWithMembersAndTypesRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration_ClassInfo_ObjectId_Name]

`0F 53 74 61 63 6B 4F 76 65 72 46 6C 6F 77 2E 41` represents the `Name` of the class which is represented by using a `LengthPrefixedString`. As mentioned, in our example the length of the string is defined with 1 byte so the first byte `0F` specifies that 15 bytes must be read and decoded using UTF-8. The result looks something like this: `StackOverFlow.A` - so obviously I used `StackOverFlow` as name of the namespace.

[image: ClassWithMembersAndTypesRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration_ClassInfo_ObjectId_Name_MemberCount]

`02 00 00 00` represents the `MemberCount`, it tell's us that 2 members, both represented with `LengthPrefixedString`'s will follow.

Name of the first member:
[image: ClassWithMembersAndTypesRecord_MemberNameOne]

`1B 3C 53 6F 6D 65 53 74 72 69 6E 67 3E 6B 5F 5F 42 61 63 6B 69 6E 67 46 69 65 6C 64` represents the first `MemberName`, `1B` is again the length of the string which is 27 bytes in length an results in something like this: `<SomeString>k__BackingField`.

Name of the second member:
[image: ClassWithMembersAndTypesRecord_MemberNameTwo]

`1A 3C 53 6F 6D 65 56 61 6C 75 65 3E 6B 5F 5F 42 61 63 6B 69 6E 67 46 69 65 6C 64` represents the second `MemberName`, `1A` specifies that the string is 26 bytes long. It results in something like this: `<SomeValue>k__BackingField`.

**MemberTypeInfo:**

After the `ClassInfo` the `MemberTypeInfo` follows.

Section `2.3.1.2 - MemberTypeInfo` states, that the structure contains:

- BinaryTypeEnums (variable in length)

> A sequence of BinaryTypeEnumeration values that represents the Member Types that are being transferred. The Array MUST:
>
> - Have the same number of items as the MemberNames field of the ClassInfo structure.
> - Be ordered such that the BinaryTypeEnumeration corresponds to the Member name in the MemberNames field of the ClassInfo structure.

- AdditionalInfos (variable in length), depending on the `BinaryTpeEnum` additional info may or may not be present.

> `| BinaryTypeEnum | AdditionalInfos          |`
> `|----------------+--------------------------|`
> `| Primitive      | PrimitiveTypeEnumeration |`
> `| String         | None                     |`

So taking that into consideration we are almost there...
We expect 2 `BinaryTypeEnumeration` values (because we had 2 members in the `MemberNames`).

Again, back to the raw data of the complete `MemberTypeInfo` record:

[image: ClassWithMembersAndTypesRecord_MemberTypeInfo]

`01` represents the `BinaryTypeEnumeration` of the first member, according to `2.1.2.2 BinaryTypeEnumeration` we can expect a `String` and it is represented using a `LengthPrefixedString`.

`00` represents the `BinaryTypeEnumeration` of the second member, and again, according to the specification, it is a `Primitive`. As stated above, `Primitive`'s are followed by additional information, in this case a `PrimitiveTypeEnumeration`. That's why we need to read the next byte, which is `08`, match it with the table stated in `2.1.2.3 PrimitiveTypeEnumeration` and be surprised to notice that we can expect an `Int32` which is represented by 4 bytes, as stated in some other document about basic datatypes.

**LibraryId:**

After the `MemerTypeInfo` the `LibraryId` follows, it is represented by 4 bytes:

[image: ClassWithMembersAndTypesRecord_LibraryId]

`02 00 00 00` represents the `LibraryId` which is 2.

**The values:**

As specified in `2.3 Class Records`:

> The values of the Members of the Class MUST be serialized as records that follow this record, as specified in section 2.7. The order of the records MUST match the order of MemberNames as specified in the ClassInfo (section 2.3.1.1) structure.

That's why we can now expect the values of the members.

Let us look at the last few bytes:

[image: BinaryObjectStringRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration]

`06` identifies an `BinaryObjectString`. It represents the value of our `SomeString` property (the `<SomeString>k__BackingField` to be exact).

According to `2.5.7 BinaryObjectString` it contains:

- RecordTypeEnum (1 byte)
- ObjectId (4 bytes)
- Value (variable length, represented as a `LengthPrefixedString`)

So knowing that, we can clearly identify that

[image: BinaryObjectStringRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration_ObjectId_MemberOneValue]

`03 00 00 00` represents the `ObjectId`.

`03 61 62 63` represents the `Value` where `03` is the length of the string itself and `61 62 63` are the content bytes that translate to `abc`.

Hopefully you can remember that there was a second member, an `Int32`. Knowing that the `Int32` is represented by using 4 bytes, we can conclude, that

[image: BinaryObjectStringRecord_RecordTypeEnumeration_ObjectId_MemberOneValue_MemberTwoValue]

must be the `Value` of our second member. `7B` hexadecimal equals `123` decimal which seems to fit our example code.

So here is the complete `ClassWithMembersAndTypes` record:
[image: ClassWithMembersAndTypesRecord_Complete]

**MessageEnd:**

[image: MessageEnd_RecordTypeEnumeration]

Finally the last byte `0B` represents the `MessageEnd` record.

Answer (score 1):

.NET serialization throws in a bunch of information other than the actual 8 bytes of your `double` (type information, etc.).  You could use a file `Stream` and then write the bytes gotten by `byte[] BitConverter.GetBytes(double)` or the `BinaryWriter` class.

There are many alternatives to .NET serialization:

- Text formats

  - XML
  - JSON
- Binary formats

  - Google Protocol Buffers
  - MessagePack

These all have their pros and cons. I especially like [MessagePack](http://msgpack.org/) and encourage you to take a look at it. For example, it will use 9 bytes to store a self-describing `double`.

Comment: While first sentence is true. The "alternatives" do the same.

Comment: @Euphoric 9 bytes to store a self-describing `double` hardly seems "the same" as 55 bytes.